# Trying to store a pointer to an abstract class in a map C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, std, stdmap

I have a program that stores a pointer to an abstract class into a map, so that I can use the data from the map to make calls to the concrete classes of the abstract class (using the factory method).

It needs to store a pointer since the class is abstract, but the problem is that when I make is a pointer, I get the error

> No matching member function to call 'insert'

My code looks as follows:

### Shape Factory Class Header

```
#ifndef ShapeFactoryManager_hpp
#define ShapeFactoryManager_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "ShapeFactory.h"
#include "CircleFactory.h"
#include "PolygonFactory.h"
#include "LineFactory.h"
#include <map>

class ShapeFactoryManager
{
public:
    ShapeFactoryManager();
    const static ShapeFactoryManager& getInstance();
    ShapeFactory createFactory(unsigned long shapeID) const;
    bool RegisterShape(unsigned long id, ShapeFactory* factory) const;

private:
    const std::map<unsigned long, ShapeFactory*>registrationTable;
};

#endif /* ShapeFactoryManager_hpp */
```

### Shape Factory Manager .cpp

```
bool ShapeFactoryManager::RegisterShape(unsigned long id, ShapeFactory* factory) const
{
    registrationTable.insert(std::make_pair(id, factory));
    return true;
}
```

The error occurs at:

```
registrationTable.insert(std::make_pair(id, factory));
```

Comment: How do you expect to insert something into a `const` map?

Comment: I know. Is `insert` a const member function? What do you think?

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh, wow, of course. I can't believe I missed that

Comment: And it has nothing to do with pointers to abstract classes or factory managers.

Comment: yeah, thanks, I realize that now

Answer (score 4):

`std::map::insert` is a not a const member function. Quite logically so, since if a map is constant, we cannot add to it or remove from it.

Remove the const qualifier of `registrationTable` and also of `RegisterShape`. If a member function needs to change state, it shouldn't be const either.